# What’s the correct way to run a long-running task in Django whilst returning a page to the user immediately?

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I’m writing a tiny Django website that’s going to provide users with a way to delete all their contacts on Flickr.

It’s mainly an exercise to learn about [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), rather than something actually useful — because the Flickr API doesn’t provide a way to delete contacts, I’m using Selenium to make an actual web browser do the actual deleting of contacts.

Because this might take a while, I’d like to present the user with a message saying that the deleting is being done, and then notify them when it’s finished.

In Django, what’s the correct way to return a web page to the user immediately, whilst performing a task on the server that continues after the page is returned?

Would my Django view function use [the Python threading module](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#module-threading) to make the deleting code run in another thread whilst it returns a page to the user?

Answer (score 5):

Consider using some task queues - one of the most liked by Django community solution is to use Celery with RabbitMQ.

Comment: I’ll certainly consider it. For a site that’s likely to remain very small-scale, what would the benefits be of going through the overhead of installing Celery and RabbitMQ (or equivalents)?

Comment: Celery is not too much overhead. You can also substitute Redis for RabbitMQ.

Comment: @dannyroa: sure, it’s just assuming I don’t have either installed already, it’s another working part to learn about, and keep updated on my server.

Comment: Have you considered using Heroku? If this is a small site, you probably won't consume all the free hours from Heroku. They have Celery as a service.

Comment: @dannyroa: I haven’t considered it, although I presume they wouldn’t have Selenium available.

Answer (score 3):

Once I needed this, I set up another Python process, that would communicate with Django via xmlrpc - this other process would take care of the long requests, and be able to answer the status of each. The Django views would call that other process (via xmlrpc) to queue jobs, and query job status. I made a couple proper json views in django to query the xmlrpc process - and would update the html page using javascript asynchronous calls to those views (aka Ajax)

Comment: Cool: so you basically rolled your own queueing system?

Comment: This is a very practical answer. In web apps, users like to see the progress of the tasks they initiated. This allows you to do just that.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: yes, and it worked quite well. And easy to set up, since setting up a separate process with xmlrpc or jsonrpc is an almost transparent task in Python.